# Algorithms for Tree Decomposition

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I want to understand the optimum algorithm for a tree decomposition of any graph. Is there any good sites where I can look up because I cannot find proper materials to understand the logic behind tree decomposition.

Comment: It's NP-hard and complicated to boot. What are you trying to apply it to?

Comment: I am basically learning the tree decomposition to solve NP hard problems on bounded tree like Maximum Independent Set.

Comment: Is the treewidth bounded? If not you're in a bit of trouble

Comment: Yes I am only considering bounded treewidth.

Answer (score 2):

The PACE (Parameterized Algorithms and Computational Experiments Challenge) challenge is a competition for implementing fast algorithms (with a worst-case exponential running time). In 2016 and 2017, one of the challenges was to compute tree decompositions. See [here](https://pacechallenge.org/past/) for reports and (inside the reports) the links to the implementations of submitted solutions.